# Is using mask for assignment faster than for loop in pytorch?

Tags: python, for-loop, pytorch, mask

I want to ask if using the mask to assign is faster than for loop in pytorch.
For example, we have the following two code blocks.

```
a = torch.tensor([-1,-1,1,1])
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > 0:
        a[i] = 0
```

```
a = torch.tensor([-1,-1,1,1])
a[a > 0] = 0
```

I'm curious about which is faster. Is there any difference?

It seems like we need two traverses for using the mask. But is there indeed difference when implemente the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tensor` supports parallel computations, so it's bound to be far quicker than iteration. You should try to use `mask` whenever possible.

A quick test on my local machine, you may try it yourself:

```
import torch
import time
import random

lst = [-1] * 5000 + [1] * 5000
random.shuffle(lst)

a = torch.tensor(lst)
b = torch.tensor(lst)

time_start = time.time()
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    if a[i] > 0:
        a[i] = 0
print(f"Iteration takes: {time.time() - time_start}")

time_start = time.time()
b[b > 0] = 0
print(f"Mask takes: {time.time() - time_start}")
```

`Iteration takes: 0.07204079627990723 \nMask takes: 0.011544942855834961`